# How to access main controller variable in Router UI controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I'm trying create a CRUD page, using AngularJS, I using Angular Router UI for pages changes

How to can I access a variable in my main `Controller`, in `controller` of route?

```
//This is my main controller:
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
]);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [
        {name: 'Daisy', description: 'Developer'},
        {name: 'Zelda', description: 'Developer'},
        {name: 'Luide', description: 'Developer'},
        {name: 'Mario', description: 'Developer'}
    ];
});
```

This is my router config
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

```
$stateProvider
    .state('list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'MyCtrl'
    })
    .state('edit', {
        url: '/edit',
        templateUrl: 'edit.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state) {
            $scope.person = {name: "", description: ""};

            $scope.click = function () {
                $state.go('list');
            };
        }
    })
    .state('add', {
        url: '/add',
        templateUrl: 'edit.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state) {
            $scope.person = {name: "", description: ""};

            $scope.click = function () {
                // HOW TO CAN I ACCESS $SCOPE.PERSONS FOR MAKE THIS PUSH?
                $scope.persons.push($scope.person);
                $state.go('list');
            };
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: if you make `edit` and `add` child routes of `list`, then you can just make `persons` a resolve. All child routes can then inject it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than create $scope.persons in a MainController, it would probably be better to use a service to store the persons object:

```
app.service("People", function () {
   this.persons = [
        {name: 'Daisy', description: 'Developer'},
        {name: 'Zelda', description: 'Developer'},
        {name: 'Luide', description: 'Developer'},
        {name: 'Mario', description: 'Developer'}
    ];
});
```

Then you can inject this into your controllers (your code above):

```
.state('add', {
        url: '/add',
        templateUrl: 'edit.html',
        controller: function($scope, $state, People) {
            $scope.person = {name: "", description: ""};

            $scope.click = function () {
                //use persons object of people service.
                People.persons.push($scope.person);
                $state.go('list');
            };
        }
    });

});
```

You can share these persons across different controllers, services, and directives through Dependency Injection. For instance, your list controller (MyCtrl) would look as follows:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, People) {
    $scope.persons = People.persons;
});
```